# Automatic migrations EF Core Postgres Aurora DB

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi, amazon-aurora

I have an ASP.NET Core 8 Web API with EF Core using a code-first approach. I am trying to apply migrations automatically using this code:

```
await using var dbContext = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<DbContext>();
await dbContext.Database.MigrateAsync();
```

If I run it locally on a Postgres docker container, it is working properly. But using AWS Aurora Postgres instance, when the `MigrateAsync` method is running, I get:

> Failed executing DbCommand (10ms)
> CREATE TABLE "__EFMigrationsHistory"
> Unhandled exception. Npgsql.PostgresException (0x80004005): 3F000: no schema has been selected to create in
> POSITION: 14

Trying manually in the database, the user has access to the `public` schema and running that query manually works. I have tried explicitly specifying schema in the `DbContext`, but still the same issue.

Any guidance?

Comment: It is your [issue](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/106057/error-no-schema-has-been-selected-to-create-in)?

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv yes the problem was of that nature, very helpful thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try to configure the searchpath in your connection string to solve this problem.

May you define the following configuration in your initial connection string:

`Server=XXXX; port=XXXX; user id=XXXX; password=XXXX; database=XXXX; pooling=true; SearchPath=XXXX`

If you have created your schema,you need SearchPath to configure the relevant schema: `SearchPath=Myschema`, else you can try deleting `SearchPath`.

Comment: As I said in the description, I have tried explicitly specifying the schema and that was not working